# Postgresql 9.6 cascading stream replication issue: physical replication slots not synced from master to slave

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am running postgresql 9.6 and trying to set up the cascading physical replications.

However, when I notice that the replication slots that set up on the master is not shown on the cascading standby units so that the downstream standby fails the basebackup when a replication slot is specified.

```
on my master:
wal_level = replica
wal_log_hints = on
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_keep_segments = 1024
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /backup/pg_archive_5432/%f && cp %p /backup/pg_archive_5432/%f'

on my standby:
hot_standby = on
```

Is this normal behavior on 9.6? If anyone is doing active-standby setup, can you check on your standby unit?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Replication slots are not replicated. So if you want to use cascading replication with replication slots, you have to create another replication slot on the first standby server. That replication slot can be used by the second standby server.

If you think about it, that makes sense: the cascading standby is not at the same place in the WAL stream as the first one, so they need different replication slots.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz Albe for the quick reply and confirmation. I notice that it works if I do not specify replication slot for downstream standby, so in this case, does it simply mean that the downstream standby is replicating from the cascading standby without replication slot, right? But I can still have multiple downstream standby even not using replication slot?

Comment: Right. But there is nothing that keeps you from creating and using a replication slot on the first standby.

Comment: indeed. Thank you @Laurenz Albe!